# PFQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: in WatchKit app works in simulator, not on watch unless iOS app is in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm writing a WatchKit app which needs to make a query to our Parse server. Because this is a network call, I follow the following procedure:

1. I make a call from WatchKit to the iOS app using `openParentApplication:reply:`
2. Inside of `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:userInfo:reply:`, I start a background task with a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` to ensure the iOS app isn't terminated immediately
3. I set up my `PFQuery` and call `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`
4. In the block I pass to the PFQuery, I reply the relevant information to the watch

I wrote this app maybe a month ago before the Apple Watch was out, and it ran just fine in the Watch simulator. Yesterday I received my Apple Watch and I was able to get the app running on the watch, but it doesn't quite work - I managed to figure out that when the iOS app is actively running in the foreground on the iPhone, then everything is great; but if the app is not active (e.g. backgrounded or terminated), then `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` never actually calls the block, and execution seems to just stop.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be going on? My initial thought was that the iOS app is getting suspended/killed before it can complete the query, but I was pretty sure the background task would prevent that.

PS. If anyone stumbles upon this question because they were looking for how to get a WatchKit app running on an actual watch, I found [this post](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/117350678170/jareds-code-signing-tips-apple-watch-edition) extremely helpful in getting it working.

Comment: Did you get the `The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply()` error with this? I'm running into some similar problems.

Comment: I never got that specific error message, but maybe that error message has since been added to Xcode 6.3.1 or 6.3.2 - that was basically the problem. See my accepted answer below, does that help? Basically, I'm pretty sure the iOS app was being killed in the background before the Parse query returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that I had several problems related to openParentApplication:reply:, and they all seem to have been resolved by using the technique from this post:

http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/11/one-weird-trick-to-fix-openparentapplicationreply

I had started a background task for my own app, but I didn't use the "bogus workaround" background task described in this post, because it wasn't necessary for me in the simulator. On the watch, though, it apparently was.